# submitting form on image click

Tags: html

I have multiple images inside one form. Depending on the image clicked a specific value should be sent with a POST.

Can this be done without javascript? (I use jquery, if not).

I tried something like this:

```
<input type="image" name="type" value="1" src="images/type1.jpg" />
```

But only the coords of the image were sent, not type=1.

Comment: No code! Can you add some please? :)

Comment: How do you display your image. <img or <input type=image? You able to use jquery.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The safe approach to this problem is to give the inputs unique names and see which one sends coordinates.

```
<input type="image" name="submit_blue" value="blue" alt="blue" src="blue.png">
<input type="image" name="submit_red"  value="red"  alt="red " src="red.png">
```

Only the successful control will send any data. So test to see if `submit_blue.x` has a value, then test if `submit_red.x` has one.

There is no need to involve JavaScript at all.

Alternatively, use regular submit buttons instead of server side image maps.

```
<button name="action" value="blue"><img src="blue.png" alt="blue"></button>
```

… keeping in mind that this will break in old-IE as it doesn't support `<button>` properly.

Comment: The button method doesn't seem very reliable, but I like the control method. A bit of extra work and a bunch of new variables, but I think I'll go with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Using jQuery you can submit the clicking on the image. You can add a id for the image or even a classe.

```
$( "#yourImageId" ).click(function() {
  $( "#yourFormId" ).submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to define multiple images, with a single "name", and multpiple "value".

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="mypage.php">
  <input type="image" name="color" value="blue" alt="blue" src="blue.png">
  <input type="image" name="color"  value="red"  alt="red " src="red.png">
</form>
```

Then, on server side, i will be able to read directly the selected value ("blue" or "red") in the "color" POST variable.

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST["color"]) && !empty($_POST["color"])) {
     $selected_color = $_POST['color'];
     echo('Selected color is ' . $selected_color);
     //"blue" or "red"
 }else{  
     echo ('No image selected');
 }
?>
```

Comment: That's invalid HTML. The `value` attribute doesn't apply to `image` inputs (and only some browsers will send the value when the image map is clicked so it is not reliable).

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
<form id="myform" action="mypage.php">
your content form here
<img scr="img1" class="submitableimage" />
<img scr="img2" class="submitableimage" />
<img scr="imgn" class="submitableimage" />
</form>
<script>
   $('img.submitableimage').click(function(){
      $('#myform').submit();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: That will submit the form if any image in the *entire* document is clicked … but not tell the server which one it was.

Comment: PS not give any code. I know it will submit for every img element. But I just want to give example. it's just selector and you can give detail like `$('img.submitableimage')` if images have submitableimage class name