# How to make an icon behave like a submit button in following scenario?

Tags: php, html, icons, form-submit

I've following piece of HTML code :

```
<form action="xyz.php" method="post" class="navbar-form pull-right">
  <input style="width: 115px;" type="text" placeholder="Enter the zip code"> <i class="icon-map-marker icon-black"></i>
</form>
```

Now you can see the line from above code :

```
<i class="icon-map-marker icon-black"></i>
```

This line is intended to display the map marker icon from bootstrap. Now what I want to achieve is make this icon act like a submit button. That is when user enters some value in a text field then after clicking on this map marker icon the form should get submit.

How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might get answer reading this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446816/submitting-form-on-image-click

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this using an image button,then you can style it as you like

```
<form action="xyz.php" method="post" class="navbar-form pull-right" id="formId">
<input type="image" src="your_image_location" alt="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<form action="xyz.php" method="post" class="navbar-form pull-right">
  <input style="width: 115px;" type="text" placeholder="Enter the zip code">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><i class="icon-map-marker icon-black"></i></input>
</form>
```

This for submit

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><i class="icon-map-marker icon-black"></i></input>
```

http://urbandoor.in/

Comment: Can you explain your code? And do you know that the `<input>` tag never has a close tag?

Comment: Pretty sure inputs don't have closing tags. ;)