# Way to display information when clicking an object

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

Is there a way to make an object submit button?

By clicking an object such as image, I want to submit.

Can anyone give me an clue?

Comment: To fetch and display data in real time, either use AJAX requests or sockets. The former is easier: when the object is clicked, send a request to a script (e.g. Python) that can fetch and respond with data from your DB. Listen for the response and use DOM/jQuery to display the info accordingly.

Comment: [This Question may help, Check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199788/how-do-i-use-an-image-as-a-submit-button)

Comment: [You can try this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45823033/4135581)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery, it's very simple:

```
// Listen for a click on an element
$('#objectId').click(function() {

    // Do something, like submit a form
    $('#formId').submit();
});
```

Comment: This is a good answer. The OP is just asking how to make any page element act as a submit button (or do another action).

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax to show information from database. For simple using ajax - download jquery or axios.
Example:

[jquery ajax documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

[axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios)